# Toast Message Not Working android app eclipse

Tags: java, android, if-statement, crash-reports

Toast message still not working any help please, runs fine but when no number entered and button is clicked app crashes and says unfortunately has stopped working. Just wanted to make my app more crash proof for users to enjoy more

code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getCanonicalName();
TextView textOne;
TextView guessText;
EditText userGuess;
Button pushMe;
MediaPlayer applause;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    varSet();






    pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Log.w(TAG, "Button Clicked");
            String randText = "";
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Random randGen = new Random();
            int rando = randGen.nextInt(10) +1;

             if((guessText.getText().toString()).length() == 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no number entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{

            int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userGuess.getText().toString());


            if ( userNumber < 1 || userNumber > 10 ) {
                guessText.setText("Please guess 1 - 10");
            } else if ( userNumber == rando) {
                guessText.setText("You Got It Right!");
                if (applause.isPlaying()) {
                    applause.seekTo(0);
                } else {
                  applause.start();
                }
            } else {
                guessText.setText("Not quite, guess again!");
            }

            randText = Integer.toString(rando);
            textOne.setText(randText);

            userGuess.setText("");
        }
        }});

}


private void varSet() {
      textOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
      guessText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
      userGuess = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      applause = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.applause);
}
```

Thank you any would be GREAT!!!

Comment: Why not use a textwatcher, link it to the textbox and disable the "button" when length of text is zero?. This way, you make sure that the user enters something. This is the right way to go.

Comment: you can use Toast.makeText(Context context, "Your Message", int duration).show()

Comment: I'm guessing your question is in the title of your post ? (make it more clearly in the post itself too).

Comment: Toast message not working? is that better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onClick method you can write this:

```
    OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if((guessText.getText().toString()).length() == 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no number entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userGuess.getText().toString());

                                     if ( userNumber < 1 || userNumber > 10 ) {
            guessText.setText("Please guess 1 - 10");
        } else if ( userNumber == rando) {
            guessText.setText("You Got It Right!");
            if (applause.isPlaying()) {
                applause.seekTo(0);
            } else {
              applause.start();
            }
        } else {
            guessText.setText("Not quite, guess again!");
        }

        randText = Integer.toString(rando);
        textOne.setText(randText);

        userGuess.setText("");
            }
        }
    };

    pushMe.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
```

Comment: I put your code in still not working have i got it in the right place code updated?

Comment: @casey what error do you get.? can you put up the log entries..?

Comment: when i run the app and enter no number then click the button the app crashes saying unfortunately the app has crashed

Comment: @casey have edited the answer and it will work fine.

Comment: ive tried still no luck for me im sure i am not putting it in the code correctly could you please update my code it would be a great help this is purely for user quality and any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Thank you i appreciate your help, time, effort

Comment: @casey tell me one thing it works fine when you enter a number right..?

Comment: yep only when no number is entered and button pressMe is clicked it crashes.

Comment: I completed a good toast message for my other app but this one having trouble with

Comment: still not working for me updated my code above this is annoying me lol but thank you for your help i do appreciate it

Comment: @casey most probably your problem is not the if/else part but the initialization part.....you are first trying to access the value before initializing `guessText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);`........add your logcat entries to your question.....

Comment: added logcat entries im screwed this is really silly i know its something simple i just finished a app with toast message but this is a little more complicated with the if statements etc

Comment: @casey what's line no 55 in your main activity

Comment: @casey you are doing this `guessText.getText()` instead it should be `userGuess.getText()` in `if` condition.

Comment: YOU ARE A LEGEND AWESOME WORK it WORKS!!! thank you for all your help i will give you good credit you have been huge help and i will tick this question for you when i can i dont have enough rep ;-( thanks so much for your help

Comment: Thank you Kindly have a nice day / evening

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a toast message, have a look at the Android developers guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html (a good place to start for all your Android development related questions)

Which all starts with something like this:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

Comment: In that case, ask that in your post. Because now it is definitely not clear from your post what you want us to answer.

Answer (score 0):

try below code :-

```
showToast(this, "your message");

public static void showToast(Activity activity, String msg)
{
    try
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_dark));
        toast.show();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```